# Circular motion of a turbomolecular pump

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

I was given the following assignment:

"The rotor of a turbomolecular pump has a diameter of $10cm$. Because of [...] (reasons) the edge of each rotor is only allowed to be accelerated by at most $a_{max} = 10^6 m/s^2$."

I am supposed to find:

1. The maximum frequency
2. The maximum angular velocity
3. The velocity v at the edge of a rotor.

I have already seen the "master solution" to this task and already tried it myself. What I am really confused about is how different both approaches were and I'd be more than happy if someone could enlighten me as to why the people writing the solution took the approach they took and if mine is any good.

First I will roughly present what they did (based on this very ugly sketch):

[image]

"The length between the endpoints $r_1$ and $r_2$ is $s(t) = \Delta\varphi(t) \cdot r$. Therefore the velocity is $v = \frac{ds(t)}{dt} = \frac{d\varphi(t)}{dt}r = \omega r$. With $\omega$ const and for a very small angle (infinetesimal) $\Delta v$ points in direction of the rotation origin. The absolute value is then $|\Delta v| \approx v \cdot \Delta \varphi$. With this the absolute value of the centripetal acceleration is $|a_z| = a_z = \frac{|dv|}{dt} \approx \frac{|\Delta v|}{\Delta t} \approx v \cdot \frac{\Delta \varphi}{\Delta t} \approx v \cdot \omega = \omega^2r$"

With that endresult and the given $a_{max}$ we can calculate all the needed quantities.

However... somehow this solution just feels off to me. I understand (at least I want to think so) the most of it, the thoughts that went into the approximations and why it is still accurate enough if we argue over infinitesimal qunatities. Though, we only learnt about circular motion and then we get such an exercise that makes me wonder how I was supposed to argue like this when we've learnt very little about it. And I was wondering, is it really needed to argue over infinitesimal values?

My own approach would have looked more like this:

We put our coordinate system (its origin) in the center of the rotation. We can look at the edge of a rotor and describe its circular motion with sin and cos. Its current position by

$s(t) = r\begin{pmatrix}cos(\varphi(t)) \\ sin(\varphi(t))\end{pmatrix}$

From there we obtain via the derivative, $v(t) = r\omega \begin{pmatrix}-sin(\varphi(t)) \\ cos(\varphi(t))\end{pmatrix}$ and also

$a(t) = r \omega^2\begin{pmatrix}-cos(\varphi(t)) \\ -sin(\varphi(t))\end{pmatrix}$

This means, the absolute value of our acceleration is $r\omega^2$, the exact same value as in the solution above. From there I can do the rest of the calculations.

My question now: Why did they not describe the rotational motion like I have attempted to do so? Is my solution bad/wrong and only works in special cases? Also as a bonus question since I have seen this in many, many examples by now. When is it a good idea to argue over infinitesimal qunatities, and when should I try to be more thorough with my calculations? The result at the end will be the same as far as I understand. I know that none of the methods might be more correct, I just can't really get into the physical thinking about it so far, knowing terms like dv and dt only from math (I am very new to physics, hence I would like to learn)

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions are fine. As far as arguing with infinitesimals goes - if that is not  an approach with which you are familiar, then it's a good idea to try to get comfortable with it, given how ubiquitous it is in physics. In this particular example, it was easy to simply write down the trajectory of the particle and then differentiate it to obtain the velocity and acceleration, but in other contexts the solution is non-trivial (indeed, finding the trajectory is usually the ultimate goal, not the starting point).

I assume you come from a background in mathematics, so you may find it helpful to sit down with some argument that uses infinitesimal quantities and then try to formalize it in the language with which you are more comfortable. That might help to establish a link between the more physical arguments you're encountering now and the more mathematical arguments you've seen before.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) And you are right about that. Do you maybe have some food for thought in which I can practice my way of thinking? I'd love to have some more scenarios in which I could try and solve things based on this way of calculating things myself, and try and see if I get myself familiarized with it.